# Wordpress "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: wordpress

When trying to access the administrator dashboard, and all the custom links which are the category page from the top menu, I'm receiving the following error:

> Error establishing a database connection.

Besides this, if I'm going on an article and after this on the category, it's working.

What's happening?

Comment: the database is ok, otherwise could not access articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a plugin that is only enabled on the administration interface is getting in the way.

SSH or FTP onto the server and move your plugins into another folder.

SSH is way faster to do this btw ;)

Comment: the problem is that I cannot acces the administrator dashboard

Comment: I did this already, it's not working, rename  the plugins folder in plugins.old, and I made another folder called plugins, but empty

Comment: oh you did that already right ignore my last post pre-edit. ;)  strikes me as very odd your "public" side is operaitonal while your admin dashboard isnt. they are both using the same wp-config.php file that has the database user name and password!!

Comment: in cpanel try updating the word press database users password.  then edit your wp-config.php to have the new password.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do this, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: you want to change the user password of the database?

Comment: not me no.. you can do it via your cpanel interface. :)  1: login to cpanel.  2: in the database section click on Mysql Databases.  3: you should see a list of current databases. that list should show the privileged user associated too it. find your word press database in the list and the user associated.  then further down will be a list of current users.. find the user associated to your wordpress database and click the reset password next to it.  give it a new password.

Comment: then in cpanel you need to go back "home".. and go to File Manager which is under the Files section.  then in file manager you need to navigate to your wordpress folder.. typically public_html contains the wp-config.php   so go into public_html.  if you have a wp-config.php in there select the file.. then up the top in the menu of the file manager select Code Editor.  this will let you edit the config file.   in the config file you want to find the line define('DB_PASSWORD', ' .... ');   add your new password in between the '' where I put the .... in my example. :)

Comment: Yes, i did this, but the same problem.

Comment: you have me stumped.